# Weird square on terminal

Tags: raspbian, python, rfid

[image]Im getting this weird square that shows up in pi terminal.
It only appears on the first byte of data read in from the UART.
The byte data is there but there square is overlapped over it.

Anyone know how to remove it?

Running:
Pi 3
Raspbian OS

Thanks

Comment: Try printing `repr(rcv)` and posting the result. Also, it might just be that the RFID reader is designed to send a character that just happens to be a special character before sending a tag code. Read the documentation for your reader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@anonymoose - So I changed my code to repr(rcv) and it worked! Just note that only one serial monitor window can be open, i.e. you cannot have both the pi terminal and python shell open at the same time to view the serial port data or it will throw up an error on the latter.

Thanks